# creating a linear search algorithm in vhdl

Tags: arrays, for-loop, search, int, vhdl

I'm trying to implement a linear search algorithm using vhdl my code is

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;


entity q1 is port(
input : in integer;
output : out integer
);
end q1;
architecture beh of q1 is
type my_array is array (0 to 6) of integer;
constant sequence: my_array := (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
begin
process(input) 

for i in sequence' range generate
    begin
        GenIf: if (input=my_array(i)) generate then
            output <=input;
        else
    output <=0; 
                end generate GenIf;
            end generate;
    end process;
    end beh;
```

the error messages I get are:

> Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at Search.vhd(16) near text "for"; 
>   expecting "begin", or a declaration statement
>
> Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at Search.vhd(18) near text
>   "generate";  expecting "then"
>
> Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at Search.vhd(20) near text "else"; 
>   expecting "end", or "(", or an identifier ("else" is a reserved
>   keyword), or a sequential statement
>
> Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at Search.vhd(22) near text "end
>   generate GenIf;";  expecting "end", or "(", or an identifier, or a
>   sequential statement
>
> Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at Search.vhd(22) near text  Info:
>   Found 0 design units, including 0 entities, in source file search.vhd

Comment: I recommend to grab a good VHDL book or read a good online tutorial. These syntax errors are easy to fix. The solution is almost given in the error message itself. Of course, you can always ask a question about an syntax error which is hard to find. And check if your VHDL compiler supports VHDL'93 OR VHDL'08.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always worth correcting the first error or the first couple. After that, it becomes pointless, because the subsequent errors depend on the first one or two. So, I've had a look at the first two:

> Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at Search.vhd(16) near text "for"; expecting "begin", or a declaration statement

Your process neeeds a `begin` statement. All processes need a `begin` statement:

```
process(input)
begin
```

> Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at Search.vhd(18) near text "generate"; expecting "then"

`Generate` statements do not belong inside processes. (In fact, you can put processes inside `generate` statements). I think you need to revise generate statements. You just need an ordinary `for loop` and `if` statement:

```
process(input) 
begin
for i in sequence'range loop
        GenIf: if input=sequence(i)  then
```

(And you meant `sequence` not `my_array`.)

After correcting those, you'll find there are plenty more different errors to correct, which are not reported because of the previous errors.